# Error with jQuery on AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to function this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/gcqsfwv8/13/)

But when I use it on my Angular app, I found some errors, and it seems to be jQuery

```
var element=$('.cds'); //the problem is right here (angular.element('.cds') is the same)
console.log(element.html());  //prints undefined,
// so, no animation
```

How can I fix it? Any ways to use jQuery edge?

index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

As the code is in bundle.js, created with browserify, should I call jQuery too? Like `var jQuery=require('jquery');`? or something. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is wrong with using angular.element? What is your end goal here?

Comment: Also, the fiddle does seem to fade the text as you want it to. I am using Chrome on Fedora (both latest).

Comment: I said the code works perfectly on jsFiddle, but not on yeoman-angular.

Comment: Just a bit of advice, you don't want to use jQuery with AngularJS unless absolutely necessary. They even say it right in their documentation. Use angular.element.

Comment: Why are you even using jQuery with angular js. Angular gives you all the flexibility with angular.elements. Using jQuery wuth angular elements you may end up in problems that will be hard to debug and will be pain

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in your code, after definition of done(). It will not work.

```
console.log($('.cds').html());
```

Now click the javascript button and select 'OnDomReady'

Now it works. You cannot use jQuery until domReady event.

EDIT
This is the most classic method for jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   /* The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated*/ 
});
```

Comment: Its a wrong advice to the wrong question :) . Help him understand to not mix jQuery with angular and not use events like ready. With angular you would like to do anything with DOM in your directives. Not anywhere else.

Comment: @Vatsal maybe when we become better we forget the rule that there is no wrong question. He obviously missed the onReady event. Whether to use $ or not with angular, THAT is another question

Comment: I agree with the first part. There are no wrong questions :) 
But I feel that the answer should point us in the right direction rather than just fixing the problem at hand

Comment: I also agree and marked your comment as useful. But can you argue that I did answer the question on how to fix the error? Also note that he clearly states he wants to use jQuery.

Comment: No denying to the fact that You correctly answered the question. But you could have done better. We all do :)

Comment: Fine, upon Vatsal's advice, the solution is the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular's built-in **jqLite** first before anything ...

```
  $scope.el = angular.element('.cds').html();

    console.log($scope.el)
```

Or if you want to user pure jquery then try searching the parent for your element an store this in a variable :

```
 var el = $('.container-class').find('.cds');

      console.log(el.html());
```

Hope this helps